# how to select check box in appium , when there is no unique id/class name?

Tags: android, checkbox, appium, appium-android

How to select the checkbox in the below screenshot?
[image]

**Tried below possibility but not working.**

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='World Music']").click();
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@index='11']").click();
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"World Music\")").click();
```

Comment: Can you share screen inspection ?

Comment: can you try this - driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("World Music")).click();

Comment: driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("World Music")).click(); -- tried this but not working.. @Manidroid

Comment: Can you post appium logs here?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your app using **Appium Desktop Inspector**. It will show you the accessibility id, id or xpath. If you don't have unique id or accessibility id, you can use the **xpath** shown in appium desktop inspector.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is to find the index of the checkbox which you want to click and click on the checkbox on that index.

This can be illustrated as below:

```
List <MobileElement> textLabels = driver.findElements (By.className ("android.widget.TextView");
List <MobileElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements (By.className ("android.widget.Checkbox");
for (int i = 0; i < textLabels.size (); i++) {
  MobileElement label = textLabels.get (i);
  if (label.getText ().equals ("<your checkbox label>")) {
    checkboxes.get (i).click ();
  }
}
```

Here you can also implement logic to check multiple checkboxes.

Comment: I tried this, it's not working... Not displaying any error in eclipse, but the checkbox is not getting selected.

Comment: You can try Android Touch Action class to tap on the checkbox instead of click.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code using coordinates, it's worked for me...

```
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("com.raaga.android:id/tv_language")));
        t.tap(int x, int y).perform();
```

If any other better approach, please post..